# How can one access custom settings directly from javascript without using Apex?

Tags: customsetting, custom

I have a custom setting of either Hierarchy or List type.

I would like to access it from javascript outside of a visualforce page. i.e. On an HTML page or in a button script.

How would one implement this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same as you would access them in visualforce:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    var url = "{!$Setup.MyCustomSet__c.URL__c}";
    alert(url);
</script>
```

If you google you won't miss it :)! [Source](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003862&language=en_US)

Comment: tried but is is not working. so now i am querying custom setting.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Do you have erros on the page? Is the setting public? I've used this method many times and it always seems to work for me...

Comment: I am using it like var url = "{!$Setup.MyCustomSet__c.URL__c}";
    alert(url); and in alert i am getting the same message {!$Setup.MyCustomSet__c.URL__c}

Comment: Forgot to mention that this only works with hierarchy. I've just tested exact same scenario and worked like a charm

Comment: this doesn't appear to work in a static resources that are javascript.